# gdal ogr2ogr produces empty files when converting kml files

Tags: bash, csv, kml, gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to covert a bunch of `.kml` files using `gdal ogr2ogr` on terminal on a machine running `Mac OS 10.12`.

There is no error message, but the output files are empty. `.kml` files are google location history downloads.

The code I am using is:

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV output1.csv 5209.kml
```

I have also tried other formats with the same luck.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON geojson.json 5209.kml
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" points.shp 5209.kml
```

Comment: Have you looked inside the `.kml` files? I often find that the ones output by Google are actually `.kmz`, and pull data from the web rather than hard-coding anything in.  I would make sure the files actually have coordinates etc. in them.  Maybe they are empty, so empty conversions are rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON --config GDAL_SKIP GML geojson.json 5209.kml
```

See the reason [here](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/kml-to-shapefile-problems-ogr2ogr/7232/2)